# slickgrid load data on page click using jquery ajax

Tags: slickgrid

I am using jquery ajax to make web api calls to load data for slickgrid. I am using slick.pager.js. I would like to only load data on a pageclick event.
So for example I want to call 25 items when the grid first loads. Then when the user clicks on page 2 I want to call the next 25 items. How can I make a jquery ajax call on a page click event?

Answer (score 0):

You have to rewrite `slick.pager.js` for this to work. Check http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example6-ajax-loading.html for some idea.

To start with, using `slick.pager.js`,:

1. Create a new object for `pagingInfo`. This will replace `dataView.getPagingInfo()`. It should contain the total recordcount and page size to construct the pager. You have to create a function within the plugin to populate this object.
2. On `constructPagerUI` function check for on `click` event, this is where you have to do the ajax call and reset the dataView using `dataView.setItems`.